# Use RAND() in User Defined Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a user defined function which calls the system `RAND()` function inside it, when I try to create the function it errors out with the following message:

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getNumber, Line 10
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.

My function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumber(@_id int)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RtnValue DECIMAL(18,4);

   SELECT TOP 1 @RtnValue = EmployeeID 
   FROM dbo.Employees
   ORDER BY EmployeeID DESC

   SET @RtnValue = RAND() * @RtnValue * (1/100)

   RETURN @RtnValue;
END
```

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Hi, you took away the acceptance, this brought me back to this and I just placed a new answer, which offers a different approach.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot call a non-deterministic function from inside a user-defined function.

I got around this limitation by creating a view, call that function inside the view and use that view inside your function, something like this......

### View Definition

```
CREATE VIEW vw_getRANDValue
AS
SELECT RAND() AS Value
```

### Function Definition

```
ALTER FUNCTION getNumber(@_id int )
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RtnValue DECIMAL(18,4);
   SELECT TOP 1 @RtnValue = EmployeeID 
   FROM dbo.Employees
   ORDER BY EmployeeID DESC

   SET @RtnValue = (SELECT Value FROM vw_getRANDValue) * @RtnValue * (1.0000/100.0000) --<-- to make sure its not converted to int
    RETURN @RtnValue;
END
```

Comment: I just posted an answer you maybe should have a look on. It concerns multiple calls to this RAND-view...

Comment: It is not about RAND being non-deterministic. It is because it has a side effect and that is why it is not allowed in UDF

Answer (score 13):

Just pass RAND() value as parameter from outside:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumber(@_id int, @RAND FLOAT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RtnValue DECIMAL(18,4);

   SELECT TOP 1 @RtnValue = EmployeeID 
   FROM dbo.Employees
   ORDER BY EmployeeID DESC

   SET @RtnValue = @RAND * @RtnValue * (1/100)

   RETURN @RtnValue;
END
```

And call as `getNumber(10, RAND())`

No any side effects.

Comment: I think this is a clean solution :), but is not scalable, what if you need more than one Rand Value ?

Comment: @DavidNoreña Then pass few Rand values as parameters.

Answer (score 9):

be carefull with RAND!

If you check this, you'll see, that multiple calls to this VIEW come all back with the same value. This is different with NEWID(). So if you really want random numbers it could be better to take NEWID() und do some "tricks" to get a number from - let's say - the first bytes...

```
CREATE VIEW vw_getRANDValue
AS
SELECT RAND() AS Value
GO
CREATE VIEW vw_getNEWID
AS
SELECT NEWID() AS Value
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test() 
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
WITH Numbers AS
(SELECT 1 AS x UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) 
SELECT *
     ,(SELECT Value FROM vw_getRANDValue) AS myRandom
     ,(SELECT Value FROM vw_getNEWID) AS myNewid
FROM Numbers
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test();
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.Test;
GO
DROP VIEW vw_getRANDValue;
GO
DROP VIEW  vw_getNEWID;
GO
```

This is a result:

1. 0,684530884058892   D1809581-BBD1-4D23-A7F9-BC697E869BB0
2. 0,684530884058892   A4BAECDE-E993-46C1-B571-7440A713C371
3. 0,684530884058892   D7A1CB65-D2BC-41B2-990D-C3BC52B056A2

A view for a random BIGINT could look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_getRandomBigInt
AS
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(VARBINARY(16),NEWID(),1)) * (-1) AS Value
GO
```

Hint: I checked this with many rows and it seems (just by sight), that this approach is not really random (all BIGINTs have the same width...). This seems to work properly:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_getRandomInt
AS
SELECT sys.fn_replvarbintoint(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),NEWID()),'-',''),4))) AS Value
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

One more idea: Use the function just to do the calculation for your business logic and hand in the non-deterministic part. In your case you seem to pick a random number between zero and the highest employeeID (what about missing IDs?)

As told before `RAND()` is difficult to use. It will come back with the same value in multiple calls. Therefore I use `NEWID`, cast it to `VARBINARY(8)` and cast this to `BIGINT`.

Have a look at this:

This function will take a `GUID` and *scale* it between the given borders:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRandomNumber(@lowerLimit BIGINT, @upperLimit BIGINT, @GuidValue UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
    SELECT ABS(CAST(CAST(@GuidValue AS VARBINARY(8)) AS BIGINT)) % (@upperLimit-@lowerLimit)+@lowerLimit
    )
END
GO
```

--This table will be filled with random values

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(RndNumber BIGINT,Tile INT);
```

--The CTE creates more than 6 mio dummy rows

```
WITH manyRows AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS nr FROM master..spt_values CROSS JOIN master..spt_values AS x
)
INSERT INTO testTable(RndNumber) 
SELECT dbo.GetRandomNumber(-300,700,NEWID()) --<-- Here I pass in the non-deterministic part
FROM manyRows;
```

--Now the table is tiled in 10 equal fragments

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT Tile
          ,NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY RndNumber) AS tileValue
    FROM testTable
)  
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET Tile=tileValue;
```

--check the random result

```
SELECT * FROM testTable
ORDER BY Tile,RndNumber;
```

--This shows clearly, that the covered range per tile is almost the same which is a proof for a fairly good random spread

```
SELECT Tile
      ,COUNT(*) CountOfNumbers
      ,MAX(RndNumber)-MIN(RndNumber) CoveredRange
FROM testTable
GROUP BY Tile
ORDER BY Tile;
GO
```

--clean up

```
DROP TABLE dbo.testTable;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetRandomNumber;
```

The result

```
T   Counts  min     max     CoveredRange
1   636553  -300    -201      99
2   636553  -201    -101     100
3   636553  -101       0     101
4   636553     0      99      99
5   636553    99     199     100
6   636553   199     299     100
7   636553   299     399     100
8   636553   399     499     100
9   636553   499     599     100
10  636552   599     699     100
```

You can see, that each tile covers roughly the same count of elements. The elements inside are covering almost the same range. This shows, that the numbers are evenly spread within the table.

Comment: Need to add 1 or you wont reach your upper limit.  (@upperLimit-@lowerLimit + 1)  test by using 1 as upper and 0 as lower

Comment: @Matt This is on purpose... But you are right, that one must be aware of this. This is the *fence-pole-question* (How many poles? How many intermediates?) I tend to avoid to reach a goal perfectly 

Comment: Its kind of the zero based vs 1 based issue.  Or if limits in this case are to be included or not.  The BETWEEN, greater than = etc. :)  I am actually going to use your technique for something just noticed as I needed some dates, bits, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use `RAND` function inside a function instead you can create simple View of `Rand` function and use it inside the `function`. This is just a workaround

**View :**

```
CREATE VIEW random_val_view
AS
SELECT RAND() as  random_value
```

**Function :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNumber(@_id int )
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RtnValue DECIMAL(18,4);
   SELECT TOP 1 @RtnValue = EmployeeID 
   FROM dbo.Employees
   ORDER BY EmployeeID DESC

   SET @RtnValue = (select random_value from random_val_view) * @RtnValue * (1/100.0)
    RETURN @RtnValue;
END
```

Comment: this function will always return `0.000` since the return value will be implicitly converted to `INT`.

Comment: @M.Ali - Am sure it wont, If I am wrong please show a demo

Comment: @Fireblade: I just posted an answer you maybe should have a look on. It concerns multiple calls to this RAND-view...

Comment: " the return value will be implicitly converted to INT"  Ooh. That's subtle. You solved my issue.

Comment: "this function will always return 0.000" - I believe it won't in this case because of the 100.0. Though I don't know the theory behind, in my experience SQL server returns integer if integer is used in calculation (/100) and decimal, if decimal is used (/100.0). Of course, `CAST` into decimal is the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get random numbers or chars with these scripts from Views (from SQL 2017):

```
-- FLOAT BETWEEN 0 AND 1
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GetRandomFloat]
AS
    SELECT  CAST('0.'+REPLACE(TRANSLATE(NEWID(), 'ABCDEF-', '#######'),'#','') AS FLOAT) AS RND
GO

-- INT FROM 0 TO 9
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GetRandomFrom0To9]
AS
    SELECT  CAST(COALESCE(LEFT(REPLACE(TRANSLATE(NEWID(), 'ABCDEF-', '#######'), '#', ''), 1), '0') AS TINYINT) AS RND
GO

-- CHAR FROM 'A' TO 'Z'
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GetRandomFromAToZ]
AS
    SELECT CHAR(CAST(ROUND(CAST('0.'+REPLACE(TRANSLATE(NEWID(), 'ABCDEF-', '#######'),'#','') AS FLOAT) * 25 + 65, 0) AS TINYINT)) AS RND
GO
```

The SELECT:

```
SELECT [RND] FROM [GetRandomFloat]
SELECT [RND] FROM [GetRandomFrom0To9]
SELECT [RND] FROM [GetRandomFromAToZ]
```