# Select random elements - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-server-2012

I need to select 10 random elements from a table.I know how to do that, else this question have been answered a million times here on SO. By my problem is the randomisation isn't good enough

I've sat up the test case showing my problem :

```
DECLARE @Random TABLE
(
  Id int, 
  [Count] int  
)

DECLARE @TestData TABLE
(
  Id int
)

declare @runs int = 0;

 WHILE (@runs <=800)
 begin
   insert into @TestData values(@runs)
   set @runs = @runs +1 
 end;

 set @runs = 0 

 WHILE (@runs <=100)
 begin
     MERGE @Random AS target  
--      USING (SELECT ID FROM @TestData  where 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), id) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int) ) 
--      USING (SELECT top 10 ID FROM @TestData order by newid()) 
        USING (SELECT top 10 ID FROM @TestData order by abs(checksum(newid())) % 100)

AS SOURCE
        ON (target.id = source.id)  
        WHEN MATCHED THEN               
            UPDATE SET Target.[Count]  = Target.[Count] + 1  
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
            INSERT (ID, [Count])  VALUES (source.ID, 1);
    set @runs = @runs +1 
end

 select [count], count(*) "count(*)" from @Random group by [count] order by 1 desc
```

As you can see I've tried several methods in order of randomisation. But every time I end up with a result like this :

[image]

So in short how do I select really random elements from a table?

Scope: SQL Server 2017, so every language feature is acceptable

Comment: Is importing a C# DLL with a custom random function in scope? Technically it's not a *language feature*

Comment: Yes it is in scope

Comment: i don't really understand what you're trying to show with the output?

Comment: Why do you think that's not selecting a random element?

Comment: Think the issue is with your output query, use this: ` select id, count(*) AS 'count(*)' from @Random group by id order by 1 desc ` and you might see your error. Remember don't use Keywords as column names.

Comment: This is just at small test example. Column names are out of scope

Comment: @podiluska because when I run this 100 times I get the same ID 6 times and only approx 600 IDs out of 800  have been selected. 

So the question is: Can i be done any better?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt So what you're saying is some IDs get selected multiple times, and some not at all? That is randomness.

Comment: @podiluska yes i know, but more like could it be done any better?

Comment: You might read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31468836/5089204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your output query I believe, although this answer doesn't verify the randomness it should show that it's pretty random.

Firstly, don't use Keywords such as `COUNT` as column names if you can help it. That's what has confused your output here.

Run this sample with 10000 runs and you should get a random set or results, but I'm not claiming it's fully randomised:

```
DECLARE @Random TABLE
    (
        Id INT ,
        Occurences INT
    );

DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        Id INT
    );

DECLARE @runs INT = 0;

WHILE ( @runs <= 800 )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TestData
        VALUES ( @runs );
        SET @runs = @runs + 1;
    END;

SET @runs = 0;

WHILE ( @runs <= 10000 )
    BEGIN
        MERGE @Random AS target
        USING (   SELECT   TOP 10 Id
                  FROM     @TestData
                  ORDER BY ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100 ) AS SOURCE
        ON ( target.Id = SOURCE.Id )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET target.Occurences = target.Occurences + 1
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( Id ,
                                       Occurences )
                              VALUES ( SOURCE.Id, 1 );
        SET @runs = @runs + 1;
    END;

SELECT   Id ,
         Occurences
FROM     @Random
ORDER BY Id;
```

**NOTE:** this should help you further your investigation but is not proof of the randomness. Further testing should be carried out.