# Function to select random Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a random id where my column `Guy_Checked` is not 1.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_rand_id()  
RETURNS int   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret int;  
    set @ret = (select top 1 Guy_ID
    FROM SantaGuys
    WHERE Guy_Checked <> 1
    ORDER BY RAND())
RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

SQL Server returns error 443 with something like...

```
"Invalid use of the "rand" operator, which has side effects, in a function."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [How to use RAND() in User Defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468836/use-rand-in-user-defined-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NEWID()` instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_rand_id()  
RETURNS int   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret int;  
    SET @ret = (SELECT top 1 Guy_ID
                FROM SantaGuys
                WHERE Guy_Checked <> 1
                ORDER BY NEWID()
               )
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

`RAND()` is really a constant through the course of the query -- it is evaluated once before the query starts processing.  `NEWID()` generates a different id each time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `newid()` [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it will create a unique value of type uniqueidentifier.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_rand_id()  
RETURNS int   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret int;  
    set @ret = (select top 1 Guy_ID
    FROM SantaGuys
    WHERE Guy_Checked <> 1
    ORDER BY NEWID())
RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer this answer which I adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772517/newid-inside-sql-server-function)...

```
-- Build the table
SELECT 123 as Guy_ID
      ,0 as Guy_Checked INTO SantaGuys;

INSERT INTO SantaGuys VALUES (234, 1);
INSERT INTO SantaGuys VALUES (456, 0);
INSERT INTO SantaGuys VALUES (567, 1);

GO


-- Create a view of RAND() to work around the Invalid use of side-effecting error
CREATE VIEW v_get_rand_id
AS
SELECT RAND() as rand_id;
GO


-- Build the function with parameters that will be in your SELECT query
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_rand_id(@my_Guy_ID as int, @my_Guy_Checked as int)  
RETURNS float    
AS   
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @my_rand_id float; 

 SET @my_rand_id = (SELECT CASE WHEN @my_Guy_Checked <> 1 
                                THEN v.rand_id 
                                ELSE 0 END as my_rand_id 
                      FROM v_get_rand_id v)

 RETURN @my_rand_id;  

END; 

GO

-- Run your query and enjoy the results
SELECT sg.Guy_ID
      ,sg.Guy_Checked
      ,dbo.get_rand_id(sg.Guy_ID, sg.Guy_Checked) as my_rand_id
  FROM SantaGuys sg;
```

Here is one result...

```
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
| Guy_ID | Guy_Checked |   my_rand_id    |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
|    123 |           0 | 0.5537264103585 |
|    234 |           1 |               0 |
|    456 |           0 |  0.227823559345 |
|    567 |           1 |               0 |
+--------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Generate ASCII tables easily from [this link](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps