# Concatenating text and Random Numbers in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am working in Google sheets script editor, and trying to do the following (but only in google scripts):

```
=CONCATENATE("61", RANDBETWEEN(1000000000, 9999999999), "@text.com")
```

The output will be similar to what follows in a single cell:

> 617876453299@text.com

When I concatenate numbers and texts in scripts I am using the following formula:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z10').setValue(61 + "@text.com")
```

Which gives the appropriate output:

> 61@text.com

I have this code to generate random numbers and fill them in cells:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z1000");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
  }
}

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var entries = [{
name : "Numbers: 1-9",
functionName : "numbers19"
 }];
 sheet.addMenu("Fill random", entries);
}
```

This gives a similar output:

> 8767654543

But when I combine these two codes I continuously receive error messages. I'm simply trying to write a function within a function, but how can I do this with the two different codes? I have tried the following, but it did not work (yeah I put the function myFunction(){ at the top and have the appropriate closing bracket):

```
 function myFunction() {
function randnumber() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
  range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
  }
} 

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var entries = [{
name : "Numbers: 1-9",
functionName : "numbers19"
  }];
}

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z10').setValue("61" + 
randnumber.call(randnumber) + "@text.com")

}
```

It gave out the following message in each cell:

> 61undefined@text.com

I will probably keep updating this post with other things I have tried, just to be as detailed as possible with this problem.

NOTE 2:
Thank you trebleCode for posting a comment and trying to help. I appreciate it! I tried to fix the line that you pointed out:

```
function myFunction() {

function randnumber () {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
  range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
   }
 }

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
 var entries = [{
 name : "Numbers: 1-9",
 functionName : "numbers19"
   }];
 }   

 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z10').setValue("61" + 
 randnumber.call(randnumber()) + "@text.com")

 }
```

The script however rendered the same message in each cell:

> 61undefined@text.com

NOTE 3:
I recently attempted this code:

```
function myFunction() {

function randnumber() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
  range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
   }
}

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var entries = [{
name : "Numbers: 1-9",
functionName : "numbers19"
}];

function copyFormulasToValues() { var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var range = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,1,1);
  }
}


SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z10').setValue("61" + 
randnumber + "@text.com")

}
```

It gives the following output in each cell:

```
61
function randnumber() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
        range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
    }
 }
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var entries = [{name:"Numbers: 1-9", functionName:"numbers19"}];
function copyFormulasToValues() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var range = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
 }
 @text.com
```

It treats the function that I'm calling as if it was in quotes. How can I fix this?

I just recently found this post on stack overflow:

[Use RAND() in User Defined Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468836/use-rand-in-user-defined-function)

It says:

"The problem is that you cannot call a non-deterministic function from inside a user-defined function.

I got around this limitation by creating a view, call that function inside the view and use that view inside your function, something like this......"

The problem is that he posted sql, but I need javascript. Is there a way to get around this problem in javascript?

Comment: Not familiar with requirements in Google Scripts, but it looks like you just need to change

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z10').setValue("61" + 
randnumber.call(randnumber) + "@text.com")`

to

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z10').setValue("61" + 
randnumber.call(randnumber()) + "@text.com")`

The difference is the added parens on `randnumber()` inside of `randnumber.call()`, and your function needs to return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does exactly what I was trying to do. It concatenates "61" with a random number and with the "@text."

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1:Z10");
cell.setFormula('=CONCATENATE("61", RANDBETWEEN(1000000000, 9999999999), 
"@text.com")');
```